# Replace PHP Array with Text Label?

Tags: php, arrays

What do you think is the best approach to replace the below array items if the value = 1 ?

My PHP

```
$tags = array(
    'checkbox_1' => $post['custom_fields']['checkbox_1'][0],
    'checkbox_2' => $post['custom_fields']['checkbox_2'][0],
    'checkbox_3' => $post['custom_fields']['checkbox_3'][0],
    'checkbox_4' => $post['custom_fields']['checkbox_4'][0],
    'checkbox_5' => $post['custom_fields']['checkbox_5'][0],
    'checkbox_6' => $post['custom_fields']['checkbox_6'][0],
    'checkbox_7' => $post['custom_fields']['checkbox_7'][0],
    'checkbox_8' => $post['custom_fields']['checkbox_8'][0]
);
```

My  Array

```
Array
(
    [checkbox_1] => 1
    [checkbox_2] => 0
    [checkbox_3] => 0
    [checkbox_4] => 0
    [checkbox_5] => 0
    [checkbox_6] => 0
    [checkbox_7] => 0
    [checkbox_8] => 0
)
```

Do I need to tinker with Array Map to give each one a label, and only output if the value is 1?

Comment: You want transform :
`Array
(
    [checkbox_1] => 1
    [checkbox_2] => 0
    [checkbox_3] => 0
    [checkbox_4] => 0
    [checkbox_5] => 0
    [checkbox_6] => 0
    [checkbox_7] => 0
    [checkbox_8] => 0
)`
to :
`Array
(
    [checkbox_1] => 'Ok'
    [checkbox_2] => 0
    [checkbox_3] => 0
    [checkbox_4] => 0
    [checkbox_5] => 0
    [checkbox_6] => 0
    [checkbox_7] => 0
    [checkbox_8] => 0
)`

?

Comment: do you want to change the array or just output? why not just `foreach($MyArray as $key=>$value){if($value >=1){echo "key is :".$key." and value is : ".$value."<br>";}}

Comment: It would be nicer if you could post in such as way that you have `$post['custom_fields']['checkboxes'] = [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...]`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, array map is good for you:

```
$array1 = array(
    'checkbox_1' => 1,
    'checkbox_2' => 0,
    'checkbox_3' => 0,
    'checkbox_4' => 0,
    'checkbox_5' => 0,
    'checkbox_6' => 0,
    'checkbox_7' => 0,
    'checkbox_8' => 0
    );

function label($val) {
    if ($val === 1) {
        return 'Checked';
    }
    return 0;
}
$array2  = array_map('label', $array1);
var_dump($array2);
```

Output is:

```
array
  'checkbox_1' => string 'Checked' (length=7)
  'checkbox_2' => int 0
  'checkbox_3' => int 0
  'checkbox_4' => int 0
  'checkbox_5' => int 0
  'checkbox_6' => int 0
  'checkbox_8' => int 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply can use `array_map()`. Example:

```
$post = [
    'custom_fields'=>[
        'checkbox_1'=>[
            1, 5, 8, 6
        ],
        'checkbox_2'=>[
            0, 5, 8, 6
        ],
        'checkbox_3'=>[
            7, 3, 2, 1
        ],
    ]
];

$result = array_map(function($v){
    $val = ($v[0] == 1) ? 1 : 0;
    return $val;
}, $post['custom_fields']);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [checkbox_1] => 1
    [checkbox_2] => 0
    [checkbox_3] => 0
)
```